# Use multiple Slick slideshows on one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slick.js

I am a beginner in web development, as part of my end-of-year project I have to create a website.

Here is my problem:
On my home page I have 3 sliders that I made with Slick, which are exactly the same. When I only put one in, it works well. But as soon as I duplicate them to have my 3 sliders, the sliders and the arrows no longer work or work but on another slider.

So my question is how can I use my 3 sliders individually?

Here is my HTML

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="post-slider">
        <h2 class="slider-title">Activités aquatiques</h2>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left prev"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right next"></i>

        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="post-slider">
        <h2 class="slider-title">Activités aquatiques</h2>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left prev"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right next"></i>

        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore labore ipsa perspiciatis inventore eos, ex laborum quis, veniam repellat nobis voluptatibus consequuntur modi nam debitis?
                        Necessitatibus, ea voluptate?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h3>Jet-ski</h3>
                <img src="" alt="" class="slider-image" />
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias, officiis dolore</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS :

```js
$('.post-wrapper').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),   
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Slick Sliders Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618158/multiple-slick-sliders-issue)

Comment: did you check this? https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1341

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Replace the class selector `.post-wrapper` by ids:

```
$('#slideshow1').slick({...});
$('#slideshow2').slick({...});
$('#slideshow3').slick({...});
```

Notice that you need to call a separate slick for each slide show. (Now you could even set different slick options for each of them, yey!)

Do not forget to assign those ids:

```
<div class="post-wrapper" id="slideshow1"> ... </div>
<div class="post-wrapper" id="slideshow2"> ... </div>
<div class="post-wrapper" id="slideshow3"> ... </div>
```

Best wishes for you web developing :-)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i'm new here.

I change the id on .post-wrapper, now i have my 3 slides, but when i click on the arrows of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd sliders it only works on the 3rd slider.

Comment: Look, the slick developer has dozens of slides on a single page: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ I suggest you check his HTML and JS source code to find differences between yours and his.

Comment: Is your page publicly accessible? Then feel free to share the URL :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've find the issue.

I had to change the .next and .prev classes on the `<i>` and put different names on each slider and do the same in js.

```
$('#slideshow1').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    nextArrow: $('.next1'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev1'),
  });   
  
  $('#slideshow2').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    nextArrow: $('.next2'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev2'),
  });   
  
  $('#slideshow3').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    nextArrow: $('.next3'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev3'),
  });  

});
```