# Slick does not allow multiple slides

Tags: javascript, slick.js

First slides are working fine. But when i add second slides its now working. I'm changing the className, why its not working? If you help me i will be glad. Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-slick').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    prevArrow: $('.prev1'),
    nextArrow: $('.next1')
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-slick2').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    prevArrow: $('.prev2'),
    nextArrow: $('.next2')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar-slick">
  <div> Test </div>
  <div> Test </div>
  <div> Test </div>
</div>


<div class="sidebar-slick2">
  <div> Test </div>
  <div> Test </div>
  <div> Test </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet a bit by adding the slick and jquery libaries en removing the script tag form the javscript block. Still no reproducable result in your snippet. Can you update it?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618158/multiple-slick-sliders-issue